# How to solve TS1005 : ',' expected using angular 2 ( quick start)

Tags: angular, angular-material, typescript-typings, angular-formly

I am trying to use @ngx-formly, altogether with the @angular-material, angular cdk etc... and along adding these third party apis to my systemsjs.config.js I encounted an ERROR TS1005: ',' expeceted ... please see error trace below : saying I have life cycle error, (meaning I have a syntax error, but i cant seem to locate the problem)

```
 node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/typings/portal.d.ts(50,39): error TS1005: ','
xpected.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-config.d.ts(1
45): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-ref.d.ts(15,4
: error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-ref.d.ts(15,5
: error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet.d.ts(19,15):
ror TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet.d.ts(19,24):
ror TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet.d.ts(20,15):
ror TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet.d.ts(20,24):
ror TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-config.d.ts(27,40): error
S1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-ref.d.ts(9,40): error TS1
5: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(57,15): error TS1005
',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(57,24): error TS1005
',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-panel.d.ts(22,33): error TS10
: ',' expected.
node_modules/@angular/material/snack-bar/typings/snack-bar-config.d.ts(20,42):
rror TS1005: ',' expected.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional l
ging output above.
```

below is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormlyModule } from '@ngx-formly/core';
import { FormlyMaterialModule } from '@ngx-formly/material';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';


import { UsertrashComponent} from "../app-users/user-trash/user-components/grid-view/usertrash.component";
import { SigninComponent } from '../app-users/user-components/user-signin/signin.component';
import { UserComponent } from '../app-users/user-components/grid-view/user.component';
import { SaveComponent } from '../app-clients/client-component/save.component';
import { TrashComponent } from '../app-client-trash/client-trash-component/trash.component';
import { ClientComponent } from '../app-clients/client-component/client.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../app/header.component';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing } from "../app-routes/app.routing";
import { GrowlModule } from "ngx-growl";

//import {jQueryToken } from ' ../app-clients/client-component/jquery.service';
//import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';

@NgModule({
 imports: [ MatToolbarModule,FormlyMaterialModule,FormlyModule.forRoot(),BrowserAnimationsModule, GrowlModule.forRoot({maxMessages:10,displayTimeMs:5000}),BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, routing, NgxPaginationModule],
 declarations: [ ClientComponent,HeaderComponent,SaveComponent,UserComponent,SigninComponent,TrashComponent,UsertrashComponent],
 bootstrap: [ HeaderComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

below is systemsjs.config.js bundles :

```
...
 // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'ngx-pagination':'npm:ngx-pagination/dist/ngx-pagination.umd.js',
      'ngx-growl':'npm:ngx-growl/ngx-growl.umd.js',
      '@ngx-formly/core': 'npm:@ngx-formly/core/bundles/ngx-formly-core.umd.js',
      '@ngx-formly/material': 'npm:@ngx-formly/material/bundles/ngx-formly-material.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
      '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',

...
```

May somebody kindly assist me ... and as for the typescipt/tcs version I just updated to version 3.0.3, and i went to change it in package.json..

Thanks so much in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: can anybody assist ?

Comment: can you check @angular/material version in your package.json and material version used by @ngx-formly/material is in sync or not ?

Comment: I have decided to change my project type from Quick start to angular 6 CLI, I have mange to get formly working without errors.. thanks @Lokesh Daiya

Comment: should I add it as answer so that you can mark it as answer?

Comment: No!, That is no answer for this problem I had. .. The solution is to simply to use CLI.instead of quick start ... because quick start doesn't handle third party API's on its own like CLI does...when I say thanks,  I am thanking you for your time.. After everyone else kept quite,  but you manage to try your best and give me your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from quick start to CLI solved my problem, because quick start doesn't handle angular third party API's...However CLI does...hope this helps someone else to this evil error.